# Windows 10 Pro for Workstations can't access anonymous file share

Tags: windows, file-sharing, server-message-block

Note: No domain is in use here, we don't have one created yet.

In our office we have a file server (A VM running Server Core 2016 with Desktop Experience) that hosts a number of file shares that are open to anyone. All steps here: (https://mariodivece.com/blog/2017/01/24/winserver-shares) were followed, and the shares are available anonymously to some people on the network.

However in our office we have 2 types of machines, whitebox machines running Windows 10 Pro (these can access the shares) and Dell Workstations running Windows 10 Pro for Workstations (These cannot access the shares)

I've tried `net use \\fileserver\sharename` to see if I can get a better error message, but this just prompts for credentials.

I have enabled the setting `Computer configuration\administrative templates\network\Lanman Workstation
"Enable insecure guest logons"`

How do I get these machines to be able to access the shares without credentials?

Edit: So I wanted to add a very odd finding, while I haven't been able to get rid of the credential prompt and just hitting Enter when it pops up doesn't work, users are able to enter ANYTHING into the username/password and get access.

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings

maybe check to make sure they are set the same with network discovery

Comment: Yes all are set to a private network, network discovery is on, password protected sharing is off.
Settings in that panel are identical between the whitebox workstations and the Dells

Comment: Check out this page.  Perhaps those machines have a saved credential somewhere that is causing an issue? (comment 2) https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/694537/some-computers-cant-access-shared-folders-host-on-network/